backtesting.py plot() not displaying EST on x (time) axis
Currently I have a dataframe where the index is a DateTime object that is configured with eastern standard time (EST).
When I plot this dataframe when using the plot() inside backtesting.py the x axis displays as UTC timezone instead of the EST time zone. Is there a way for me to change this to display EST timezone?
Thanks!

I have the same issue :( Let me know if  you found a solution.
